# Get the waypoints of an alternative route with google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Till version 3.27 of the google maps javascript api you can get the waypoints by looping through the via_waypoints-Array of the [leg-Objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsLeg) of the alternative route.

The problem is that the via_waypoints-attribute for alternative routes in the direction response is now [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#change-in-via-waypoints-in-directions-service-response), so there is IMHO no (easy) way of getting the alternative/discriminating waypoints and therefore no way of requesting the alternative route or list the waypoints of the resulting route.

Is there a way to get somehow the waypoints of the alternative route?

Any thoughts, any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't see any other way of getting these waypoints than following the suggestion of Google:

> Version 3.27 will be the last version of the API that supports via_waypoints in alternative routes.
>
> The recommended approach is to request alternative routes, then display all routes as non-draggable plus the main route as draggable. Users can drag the main route until it matches an alternative route. The via_waypoints field is available on the resulting route (dragged by the user).

As from version 3.27+ the alternative routes won't be returned, I suggest you to either make seperate requests for the alternative routes or to switch to another directions service provider.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Unfortunately this is not the answer I was hoping for...maybe someone else has an idea how to get the missing waypoints in some way.